# how to stop php from automatically converting binary to decimal

Tags: php, binary, hex

Hello I have a situation like this:

I need to submit a binary value to a php function. Php automatically converts this number to a decimal number. for example if I pass `function(10000000000000001000000000000000)` then I get the value `1.0E+31`. I would like the binary number to be interpreted as a string in the function. Now I understand that if I surround the number with quotes as so `function("10000000000000001000000000000000")` then it will be submitted as a string like i need it to, but this is not possible because I am writing a class which other people will use and I don't want to tell them that they have to submit the binary number as a string. Are there any other options or maybe code that I can put into the class in order to get the string. Also I cannot just convert the converted decimal to binary because it rounds it off and I get the wrong values.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You'd be better off passing it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that PHP's built in functions handle binary numbers as strings: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not have a binary integer literal until 5.4, but it does have hex and octal literals if you don't mind converting between those instead (converting bin/oct/hex by hand is very easy).  Otherwise, you have to stick with a string.